# MySQL: copy data from table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to copy "user1_id" & "user2_id" from "battle" table to new table called "user_battle",

tables structure:

"battle" table (structure):

```
id     user1_id     user2_id
1          1          2
2          1          3
3          2          3
4          2          4
5          1          4
```

"user_battle" table (structure): (should be filled like this)

```
battle_id      user_id
   1               1
   1               2
   2               1
   2               3
   3               2
   3               3
   4               2
   4               4
   5               1
   5               4
```

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `union all` to get the data you want:

```
select id, user1_id
from battle
union all
select id, user2_id
from battle;
```

You can put `insert into user_battle(battle_id, user_id)` before this statement for the `insert`.

Answer (score 1):

`insert into` allows you to use a `select` to effectively "copy" data from one table to another.

By using `union` you can get separate rows for `user1_id` and `user2_id`.

```
insert into user_battle (battle_id, user_id)
(
  select id, user1_id from battle
  union
  select id, user2_id from battle
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a union.

```
INSERT INTO user_battle (battle_id, user_id)
SELECT id, user1_id
FROM battle
UNION ALL
SELECT id, user2_id
FROM battle;
```

Answer (score 0):

`insert into user_battle select id, user1_id from battle`
And
`insert into user_battle select id, user2_id from battle`